# Linked List is always null isEmpty() method I am trying to create is not working

Tags: java, object, linked-list, null, is-empty

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Student st1 = new Student("Adams", 3.6, 26);
    Student st2 = new Student("Jones", 2.1, 29);
    Student st3 = new Student("Marcus", 4.0, 53);

    System.out.println("Testing non-recursive code");
    LinkedListStud LL = new LinkedListStud();
    //checks if linked list is empty
    System.out.println("Linked list is empty?: " + LL.isEmpty());     
    //adds students to the linked list from the front
    LL.addFront(st3);
    LL.addFront(st2);
    LL.addFront(st1);
    //adds students to the linked list from the back
    LL.addTail(st1);
    LL.addTail(st2);
    LL.addTail(st3);
    //prints linked list non-recursively
    LL.printLL();

    System.out.println("Linked list is empty?: " + LL.isEmpty());
}
```

this is my testing method ^ as you can see I am filling my list with student objects. The printLL() method shows all 6 objects are in fact in the array.

```
public boolean isEmpty()
{
    Boolean e;
    if (list==null)
        return e=true;
    else
        return e=false;
}
```

This is my isEmpty() method. The parameters and data type is specified by my professor. For some reason my list always equals null even though it should contain 6 objects the second time I use the method. What am I missing?

My entire linked list class

```
 public class LinkedListStud
{
    private Node list;

    public LinkedListStud()
    {
        list = null;
    }

    public void addFront(Student s)
    {
        Node oneNode = new Node(s);
        oneNode.next=list;
        list=oneNode;
    }

    public void addTail(Student s)
    {
        Node current;
        Node oneNode = new Node(s);
        if (list==null)
            list=oneNode;
        else
        { 
            current=list;
            while (current.next != null)
                current=current.next;
            current.next=oneNode;
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        Boolean e=true;
        if (list!=null)
            return false;
        else 
            return e;
    }

    public Student bestStudent()
    {
        Student bestStudent=list.data;
        while (list.next!=null)
        {
            if (list.next.data.getGpa()>list.data.getGpa())
            {
                Student temp = list.data;
                list.data=list.next.data;
                list.next.data=temp;
            }
            list=list.next;
        }
        return bestStudent;
    }

    public void printLL()
    {
        while (list!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(list.data);
            list=list.next;
        }
    }

    public void printLLRec(Node list)
    {
        if (list!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(list.data);
            printLLRec(list.next);
        }
    }

    Student bestStudRec(Node list)
    {
        Student bestStudent = list.data;
        if (list!=null)
        {
            if (list.next.data.getGpa()>list.data.getGpa())
            {
                bestStudent=list.next.data;
                bestStudRec(list.next);
            }
        }
        return bestStudent;
    }

    private class Node
    {
        public Student data;
        public Node next;
        public Node(Student s)
        {
            data=s;
            next=null;
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            return "" + data;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your LinkedList class?

Comment: You can just return true/false without assigning to e.

Comment: Can you add you printLL method ?

Comment: Where are your `addTail` and `addFront` methods?

Comment: I didn't include them for brevity. I can add them if that will help.

Comment: Yes, add them please. It would help.

Comment: Okay I added them

Comment: Did you get NullPointerException at the first System.out.println("Linked list is empty?: " + LL.isEmpty());  ? I guess not

Comment: No it works fine the first time. But it doesn't print false the second time. Also the isEmpty() is rewritten because I was trying to fix it sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here:

```
public void printLL()
{
    while (list!=null)
    {
        System.out.println(list.data);
        list=list.next;
    }
}
```

You replace list variable with nested list until it becomes null. Last iteration there set your LL.list to null, then while checks it and goes out. If you modify while like:

```
public void printLL()
{
    while (list!=null)
    {
        System.out.println(list.data);
        if (list.next == null) break;
        list=list.next;
    }
}
```

you will get what you need, but your root LL will have replaced value from last Node.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from @Vadim 's answer, if you want to print it out without changing the internal list, you can introduce a local variable.

`public void printLL()
    {
        Node temp = list;
        while (temp!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(temp.data);
            temp=temp.next;
        }
    }`